# Pthread_create for threading client send and receive functions

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, pthreads, client

I am writing a chat application in C++ and have working client and server classes. I am now trying to get my client to be able to read and write from/to the server in parallel. I know that I must create two threads, one for reading and one for writing. What I do not know is what I should use for a start routine for these threads. I have looked at all the man pages and cannot seem to fully understand. Can someone shed light on this subject and possibly help me out? Let me know if I missed any important details.

Comment: Are you asking how to implement a thread function (like `void* thread_function(void* parameters) { /* thread code here */ }`), or are you asking how you might implement the read/write (client/server) in a thread?

Comment: A little bit of both, can you first explain how a thread function works?

Answer (score 0):

Your start routine should be a top-level function that you create which accepts a void pointer for an argument and returns a void pointer. For example:

```
void *trivial_start_routine(void *client_ptr)
{
    client_class *my_client = (client_class*) client_ptr;
    while(my_client->working()) {
        try {
          my_client->read_from_server();
        } catch(exception all_exceptions) {
           // Be sure to catch every exception.
           // Pthreads cannot handle a C++ exception
           // unwinding the stack.
        }
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

According to the Linux man page for *pthread_exit*:

> Performing a return from the start function of any  thread  other  than
>   the  main  thread  results in an implicit call to pthread_exit(), 
>   the function's return value as the thread's exit status.

Then, to start the thread, you do something like this:

```
pthread_t start_reader_thread(client_class *my_client) {
    pthread_t thread;
    int status;

    status = pthread_create(&thread, NULL, trivial_start_routine, my_client);
    if(status != 0) {
        // status is an error number. See the man page for pthread_create.
    } else {
        return thread;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to mention about joining the thread before program exit (that caused me many a headache when I first started multi-threaded programming).

Comment: @txtechhelp one reason for the headache is that such joining is not always necessary and, if it can be avoided, it should be.

Comment: @MartinJames, why? Just curious. I agree you don't always need to join a thread if you don't need to wait on it, but to say to avoid joining a thread doesn't make sense given why you join a thread. If I spawn a thread and my program ends before my thread does, the thread will be killed and my program will not execute as expected, how could I avoid that?